# What was the probability that it rained?

Tags: probability

I have a question from maths class.

"My team has a 2/3 chance of winning a match if it rains. My team has a 1/5 chance of winning if it is dry on the day. The probability of it raining on the day is 1/4."

One of the subquestions asks:

"If the team won on the match, what was the probability that it rained on the day?"

I feel like the question is wrong and the answer should be 1/4 regardless of the outcome of the match. My teacher says the answer is 10/19.

Comment: Your team winning and raining are intertwined as indicated by given probabilities. If it rains, team's winning chances increase due to favored ground conditions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider $60$ different days.  On $15$ of those days it rained and on the other $45$ days it was dry.

Your team won on $\frac 23 \cdot 15=10$ of the rainy days and on $\frac 15 \cdot 45 =9$ of the dry days.  So if your team won, the probability that it rained was $\frac {10}{19}$.

The point of the question is that the disparity in probability of victory between rainy and dry days means that knowing that your team won gives you information about whether it rained.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition of conditional probability you have

$$\mathbb{P}[R|W]=\frac{\mathbb{P}[R\cap W]}{\mathbb{P}[W]}=\frac{\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{3}\times \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}\times \frac{3}{4}}=\frac{10}{19}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is correct. The probability that it rained is not $\frac14$.

For an intuitive sense, imagine the case when your team has a $0$ chance of winning on a dry day. Then, if your team won the match, you **know** it was raining, so the probability of raining was $1$.

For actually solving the problem, use the **hint**:

Bayes' theorem.